# Как вставить переменную в регулярное выражение?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пишу код который должен искать файлы с разными расширениями, выглядит так:

```
<div class="main-box">
<div class="text-wrap">
    <label for="input-text">Paste the text below</label>
    <textarea name="input-text" id="input-text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <label for="format">File format (optional)</label>
    <input type="text" id="format" placeholder=".png">
    <button id="submit-btn">Find</button>
</div>
<div class="text-wrap">
    <label for="output-text">Finded:</label>
    <textarea name="output-text" id="output-text" cols="30" rows="10" disabled></textarea>
</div>
```

```
<script>
format = $('#format').val()
test = '\S*\' + format
var regex = new RegExp(test, 'g')
$('#submit-btn').click(function(){
    let str = $('#input-text').val();         //получение текста
    str = str.match(regex);                  //обработка
    $("#output-text").val(str.join("\n"));  //вывод
});
</script>
```

Проблема в обратном слэше, не получается его экранировать так, чтобы всё работало

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам ничего не мешает сделать рег выражение из строки, которую вы можете сконструировать как вам угодно

```
const regex = new RegExp(str);
```

Проблема экранирования посмотрите [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Пример эквивалентов оттуда

```
 var re = /\w+/;
 var re = new RegExp('\\w+');
```

Или

```
  /ab+c/i;
  new RegExp('ab+c', 'i');
```

В вашем конкретном примере используйте две `\\` в строке если в результате хотите один `\` в выражении.

```
format = $('#format').val()
test = '\\S*\\' + format
var regex = new RegExp(test, 'g')
```